# How to understand that my server was used for ssh-bruteforce attack?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

my VPS provider told me that there was an ssh-bruteforce attack from my server. I've checked sessions with "last" command, but there was no active root session during attack time. The "lastb" output shows a lot of unsuccessful attempts. I suppose someone has hacked my server, if so, how to understand when he logged in, which processes did he start (this is a bot of course)?

I've changed the root password today, but after that there was a new session from unknown for me IP-address, how was this possible? What should I do to remove all malware if one was installed? I'd like to assure that there actually was an attack from my server, but have no idea how to check unsuccessful ssh connections from my VPS or find any other proof.

I've tried to analyze sessions history, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please see [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/a/218011)

Comment: Most importantly for now, cut off all internet access ASAP, if that is not possible, shut the server down. "there was a new session from unknown for me IP-address" If that is the case, your server is 100% compromised.